Error Implementing certificate-based authentication
I am trying to implement Certificate based authentication for one of my message flows, below is the scenario
I have a Message Flow that gets triggered using "File Input" Node and uses HTTP Request Node to invoke external endpoint.
It is certificate based authentication with the endpoint.
I received a .pfx file using which I extracted .crt and tried installing it in Truststore. However, I am getting "403-Unauthorized" error while calling the endpoint.
Not sure if I have configured wrongly or missing any steps.
Error from HTTP Request node:
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
<h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
<h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.       </h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>

I tried installing the certificate in Truststore. Still getting same 403 - Unauthorized error.
